# Position pseudoelement between track and thumb of input type range

Tags: css, html, z-index

I need to put a pseudo element with z index lower than the thumb of an input type range but higher than the track of it, I got the following:

html:

```
<div class="range">
  <input type="range" name="" class="progress" value="0" max="100" min="0" />
</div>


.range{
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50vw;
}

.range::before{
   content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
   width: 13px;
   height: 13px;
   -moz-border-radius: 13px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
   border-radius: 13px;
   border: 2px solid #FFE000;
   background-color: #242526;
   z-index: 50;
}

input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  z-index: 100;
}


input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  background: #FFE000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 0px solid #FFE000;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

the z-index is working for the full pseudoelement and the full range, but I havent managed to put it in between. Is this possible?

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cn5va061/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this i suppose: https://jsfiddle.net/cn5va061/2

Changed Z-index on `before` element and gave slider thumb Relative positioning for upper `z-index`

Comment: Thanks! that was it

Comment: This is not working on Firefox (tested on v96).